# CouchDB - Mango Query to select records based on complex composite key

Tags: database, couchdb, couchdb-mango

I have records with keys looking like this:

1. "001_test_66"
2. "001_testab_54"
3. "002_testbc_88"
4. "0020_tesgdtbc_38"

How can I query a couchdb database using Mango queries based on the first part of the key (001 or 002). The fourth one should fail if I search on '002'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$regex` operator described in chapter [Condition Operators](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#condition-operators) of CouchDB API Reference. In below example, I assumed `_id` to be the key you want to search by.

```
"selector": {
    "_id":  {
        "$regex": "^001.*"
    }
}
```

Here's an example using CURL (replace `<db>` with the name of your database).

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST http://localhost:5984/<db>/_find -d '{"selector":{"_id":{"$regex": "^001.*"}}}'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Will it work like this also ? "$regex": "^001"

Comment: @Mi Yil: `"$regex": "^001"` should also work and is probably even better.

Comment: One more question, I'm trying to do it like this: "{\"selector\":{\"_id\":{\"$regex\":'^001'}}\"]}"

Comment: Have I been doing someonething wrong in that code piece?

Comment: @Mi Yil: Hard to say if your code is fine without knowing in what context it gets executed. I added an example to my answer that illustrates how this can be done with CURL.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your response! My very last question, I want the fourth value to be an "_", an underscore. Can you please provide me with infomration, it's almost working!

Comment: Found it:          "$regex": "^000_"
Thanks for all your help sir!